# Do I need to go to contrib to manage multiple files for a single node?

Tags: files

I have created a content type called 'audio'. I've added a field of type `File` which can take three values. So far so good. I've created a new audio node, given it a title and some body text and then uploaded two audio files. The same file but one is mp3 the other is ogg.

Now, I was expecting Drupal to keep track of which files belong to the node, but it only seems to keep track of the first file I uploaded. The second file *is* recorded in `{file_managed}`, but the `{field_data_field_file}` is not recording the multiple fids that belong to a nid of type audio. In the `field_file_fid` column there's only space for one fid, not an array of fids.

Do I need to go to contrib ([FileField](https://drupal.org/project/filefield)?) to manage multiple files uploaded to a single node? or am I doing something wrong? I'm hesitating to go to contrib because this seems like a basic feature that ought to be in core.

Thanks.

Comment: The field tables store multiple values as multiple entries, not with arrays.

Comment: Thanks. At least I know something's gone wrong. That's kinda what I expected to see: multiple entries. So in my field_file table for nid 1 which has two file uploads, should there be two rows, both with an entity_id of 1, and each with different file fids, say fid 3 and fid 4?

Comment: I was actually trying to say everything it's fine ;) Are you saying that when editing the node again, the two files are not listed on the node form? If they are, clearly Drupal tracks them. If you use D7, the FileField module is what you use already. File Entity is the new thing, but I don't see why you'd need it for this.

Comment: It's working correctly now, thanks. All I can think is that after uploading the second files I forgot to hit save. Time to go to bed probably :)